# How to ceilng the value using mdx query

Tags: ssas, mdx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnexe.png)How to ceilng the value using mdx query., for this query the output value is 2.2, but i need round to 3.

```
WITH MEMBER [AssessmentCouting] AS COUNT(NonEmpty (
                                { 
                                    ( 
                                     ([DimAnchorDate].[Anchor Date].[Anchor Date]),
                                     ([DimAnchorDate].[Calendar Quarter Des].[Calendar Quarter Des]),
                                     ([DimAssessment].[AssessmentText].&[167]&[Care Management Follow up Encounter]),
                                     ([DimAssessment].[QuestionText].[QuestionText]),
                                     ([DimPatient].[Patient Key].[Patient Key]),
                                     ([DimPatient].[Full Name].[Full Name])
                                    )
                                }, 
                        { [Measures].[ProgramAssessmentPatientCnt] }))/10


SELECT [AssessmentCouting] ON 0 
FROM [NavigateCube]
```

Comment: Do you need something like iff(x > cint(x), x+1,x)?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, i used like this                                   IIF(AssessmentCouting > CINT(AssessmentCouting),ROUND(AssessmentCouting)+1,AssessmentCouting)

Comment: @DanyloKorostil, but it should be IIF right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
WITH MEMBER [AssessmentCouting] AS COUNT(NonEmpty (
                                { 
                                    ( 
                                     ([DimAnchorDate].[Anchor Date].[Anchor Date]),
                                     ([DimAnchorDate].[Calendar Quarter Des].[Calendar Quarter Des]),
                                     ([DimAssessment].[AssessmentText].&[167]&[Care Management Follow up Encounter]),
                                     ([DimAssessment].[QuestionText].[QuestionText]),
                                     ([DimPatient].[Patient Key].[Patient Key]),
                                     ([DimPatient].[Full Name].[Full Name])
                                    )
                                }, 
                        { [Measures].[ProgramAssessmentPatientCnt] }))/10

MEMBER [AssessmentCoutingRounder] AS 
IIF(
    [AssessmentCouting] > Int([AssessmentCouting]), 
    Int([Measures].[AssessmentCouting])+1,
    [Measures].[AssessmentCouting]
)

SELECT {[AssessmentCouting],[AssessmentCoutingRounder]} ON 0 
FROM [NavigateCube]
```

Comment: Thank you responding, but when AssessmentCouting = 2.8 then it will show 2.8 only, in this case i need to 3

Comment: Haven't mentioned that behaviour before. You have to use Int() instead Cint() and it will wok just fine.

Comment: Ok Thank You @Danylo

Comment: No problem, mark it answered if your issue is resolved.

Comment: i got it finally round function                                                      
MEMBER RowCount AS IIF(AssessmentCouting > CINT(AssessmentCouting),ROUND(AssessmentCouting)+1,ROUND(AssessmentCouting))

Comment: I doesn't matter here whether you are using Round() or Int(). Int() is more clear because you don't need to use two functions.